# Convert pandas dataframe to parquet format and upload to s3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3, parquet

I have a list of parquet files that i need to copy from one S3 bucket to another s3 bucket in a different account. I have to add a few columns to the parquet files before I upload.
I am trying to read files to a pandas dataframe and I am adding columns and converting it parquet but it does not seem to work.

here is what I am trying.
my_parquet_list is where I am getting the list of all keys.

```
for file in my_parquet_list: 
    bucket = 'source_bucket_name'
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    s3_obj = s3.Object(bucket,file)
    s3_obj.download_fileobj(buffer)
    df = pd.read_parquet(buffer)
    df["col_new"] = 'xyz'
    df["date"] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    df.to_parquet(buffer, engine= 'pyarrow', index = False)
    bucketdest = 'dest_bucket_name'
    s3_file = 's3_folder_path/'+'.parquet'
    print(s3_file)
    s3.Object(bucketdest, s3_file).put(Body=buffer.getvalue())
    print('loaded')
```

Comment: Can you describe the error you are observing in more detail?

Comment: @BlakeG The error I am getting is "ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[ms] would lose data: 1607457464128523000".

Comment: Did you Google the error message? When I searched for it I discovered there is a configuration setting to alter which will permit the loss of data.

Comment: @BlakeG i did not google it, that is the error message I am getting and this is the line which which is causing the error df.to_parquet(buffer, engine='pyarrow', index = False)

Comment: Always google your literal error messages as one of the first steps in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `pip install s3fs`, then configure you aws CLI, finally you can just use `df.to_parquet('s3://bucket_name/output-dir/df.parquet.gzip',index=False)`